# Relation between these two series

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

Assume a constant $\alpha$ and $N$ positive integers $\{n_1,...,n_N\}$. What is the relation between $\frac{N\alpha}{\sum_i{n_{i}}}$ and $\sum_i{\frac{\alpha}{n_{i}}}$ when $N\rightarrow\infty$?

$N$ is not necessarily infinite, I just want to compare these two series when $N$ becomes large enough.

Note: statistically speaking, this represents the relation between $\mathbb{E}\{\frac{X}{Y}\}$ and $\frac{\mathbb{E}\{X\}}{\mathbb{E}\{Y\}}$.

Comment: $\sum n$ and $\sum 1/n$ both diverge, if sum is over $n=1, ..., \infty$

Answer (score 0):

The triangular number formula gives $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ so $\frac{1}{\sum n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

However, $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is the harmonic series which diverges as $n \to \infty$.

Edit: You have dramatically edited your question and this answer is no longer relevant. Please make a new question for next time.

Comment: @user350875 In your new question, what is $\alpha$?, and can you give the proper indices for the sums?